# default filter in interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I make custom default filter in interactive report? That filter is loaded when reset button is pressed.

Also how can I make this filter to be set with some values, e.g. filter is initialized with current date and rows that only relates to current date are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make custom default filter
>   in interactive report? That filter is
>   loaded when reset button is pressed.

Once you are happy with your report, starting from the Interactive report actions menu --> select save report --> change the select list to "As Default Report Settings"

> Also how can I make this filter to be
>   set with some values, e.g. filter is
>   initialized with current date and rows
>   that only relates to current date are
>   shown.

Have you tried using a row filter which are described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17556_01/doc/user.40/e15517/app_comp.htm#sthref1149) in the documentation?

From the Interactive report actions menu --> select filter --> select row radio button and then write the expression that you want.

The example below is the expression that I used to show me only employees that have a hiredate equal to or greater than today.

[image]